# Flutter & iOS: fatal error: module 'webview_flutter_wkwebview' not found

Tags: ios, flutter, webview

I am trying to implement webview with Flutter. But I keep on getting the following error

```
fatal error: module 'webview_flutter_wkwebview' not found
```

Then I added:

```
<key>io.flutter.embedded_views_preview</key>
    <true/>
```

FYI, I use `webview_flutter: ^3.0.0`.

But nothing changes. Please help me out with this.

Comment: try uninstalling the app and then reinstalling it

Comment: @Pokaboom I got the same result

Comment: Try this :  https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_webview_plugin/issues/657

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using `v4.2.2` and finally got it fixed after 2 days.

step 1: downgrade to webview_flutter: ^4.2.0

step 2: Use copy the content of this podfile [podfile.link](https://github.com/flutter/codelabs/blob/master_archived/webview_flutter/step_12/ios/Podfile): https://github.com/flutter/codelabs/blob/master_archived/webview_flutter/step_12/ios/Podfile